# What relation I need to do in this model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created a table for ad detail and I wondering which relation I should use in the adDetail model. The migration file looks like that. please help me

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdsDetailsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ads_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('ad_id');
            $table->string('token', 60)->unique();
            $table->longText('session_data');
            $table->boolean('session_status')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('ad_id')->references('id')->on('ads');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ads_details');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're referring to the relationship of the Model objects, right? In that case, I'd suggest you take a look at Laravel's documentation and create your User, Ad and Ad Detail model objects https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably a relation to Ad and User Model

in AdDetail Model

```
public function ad()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Ad::class);
}
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```